# How to add index to existing data in neo4j

Tags: indexing, neo4j

I have more than 31,023,432 nodes and 41,764,600 relationships in my NEO4J 2.0.3 db. I missed adding the index while doing the data import. Is there a way to reindex the existing database?
Without index, the queries are performing poorly. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an index or constraint. Your data will be automatically indexed in the background. When it is finished the index will show up as `ONLINE` when you run the `:schema` command from the Neo4j-Browser. Then it will be used by your queries and transactionally updated.

E.g.

`CREATE INDEX ON :Person(name);`

See more in the [Neo4j Manual](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.0.3/cypherdoc-labels.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did exactly as you said but that did not work.

neo4j-sh (?)$ schema<br>
No indexes<br>

No constraints<br>
neo4j-sh (?)$ CREATE INDEX ON :ORDER(scheduleDate);<br>
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Indexes added: 1
166 ms
neo4j-sh (?)$ schema
Indexes
  ON :ORDER(scheduleDate) ONLINE

`

Comment: After that when I use the index in the start query i get index does not exist : 
START n = node:ORDER(scheduleDate='20140304000000') return n;    
MissingIndexException: Index `ORDER` does not exist